# SVG stroke-dashoffset overdraw issue in safari

Tags: css, animation, svg, safari

So heres my test code
http://output.jsbin.com/wuzibewiwa

The issue I am having is that in safari it seems like you can't have positive dasharray overflow.
to make this clear in chrome you can overflow the dash array before the start point and nothing will show and also after the end point and nothing will show.

In safari this seems to act much differently showing the fill animation twice basically which makes me think that the positive overflow causes issues.

Is there a solution to this in Safari?

Comment: You could draw a white stroked version on top?

Comment: That wouldn't draw the linecap style correctly.